# Manage X label in GNU

Tags: gnuplot

I have x-label range like this: 2.0237*e^10 to 15.055*e^10.
Now when I draw the graph then X-label values overlap.

How can I manage this without changing font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "set xtics" to define a larger distance between the xlabel major tics.
You can also use "set format x " to define a more suitable format for the x-axes:

For example:
This draws the xlabel tics only at 2*e^10, 4*e^10, 6*e^10...

```
set xtics 2E10
```

This will display the label tics in a more compact form:

```
set format x "%1.0E"
```

You might also find this very helpful:
http://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf3330/scripting/doc/gnuplot/Kawano/tics-e.html#3.1